# C++ error: "use of deleted function" with minGW_32, Qt 5.7.0, windows 10

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5

I get following error message trying to compile following code

> ```
> main_LoSignalDelayOnCoherence.cpp:56: error: use of deleted function 'CrossSpectrum::CrossSpectrum(const CrossSpectrum&)'
> ```

```
CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ) };
```

The corresponding line generating the error in `main_LoSignalDelayOnCoherence` is:

```
CrossSpectrum XS[numOfFFT] = {
    CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ),
    CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ),
    CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ),
    CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ),
    CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ),
    CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ),
    CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ),
    CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ),
    CrossSpectrum( frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING ) };
```

The header file of `CrossSpectrum` is:

```
class CrossSpectrum : public rFFT
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CrossSpectrum(
    SLArrayIndex_t FFTLength = 1024,                    // Power of 2
    const SLWindow_t windowType = SIGLIB_RECTANGLE,
    QObject *parent = NULL );   
    ~CrossSpectrum();
// notice, no assignment and copy constructor defined
...
}
```

The corresponding implementation file is:

```
CrossSpectrum::CrossSpectrum ( 
                                SLArrayIndex_t FFTLength,
                                const enum SLWindow_t windowType,
                                QObject *parent )
                                : rFFT( FFTLength, windowType, true, parent )
{
    mpTemp = SUF_VectorArrayAllocate( mFFTLength );
    mpTemp2 = SUF_VectorArrayAllocate( mFFTLength );
    mpCplxTemp = SUF_ComplexRectArrayAllocate( mFFTLength );
    mpCplxTemp2 = SUF_ComplexRectArrayAllocate( mFFTLength );
    mpCplxTemp3 = SUF_ComplexRectArrayAllocate( mFFTLength );

    mpAccumulatedAutoSpectrum1 = SUF_VectorArrayAllocate( mFFTLength );
    mpAccumulatedAutoSpectrum2 = SUF_VectorArrayAllocate( mFFTLength );
    mpAccumulatedCrossSpectrum = SUF_ComplexRectArrayAllocate( mFFTLength );

    reset();
}
...
```

I understand that the compiler is complaining that a copy constructor has not been provided, which is also not intended as such a construct would not make sense.
My questions are:

1. I do not understand where a copy should be done!
2. how can I resolve this issue?

Notice: the software was compiling under Microsoft VC9 (Visual Studio 2008) and Qt4.8.

Comment: Does `Q_OBJECT` make a class non-copyable?

Comment: ...or the base class `rFFT` may be such.

Answer (score 1):

Elements are expected to be copied when you initialize your array. More 'direct' brace-initialization seems to be working here:

```
CrossSpectrum XS[numOfFFT] = {
    { frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING },
    { frameLen, SIGLIB_HANNING }};
```